# Can you cast Geas on yourself?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

I'm pretty sure there's no RAW reason why this spell can't be cast on oneself. Is this the case? As an example, could a recovering alcoholic cast [*geas*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/geas) on themselves to refrain from drinking?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Certainly, but you could also remove it

It has been established that in normal circumstances, [you can see yourself](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/859636017342668801). So you are a valid target of this spell.

But it's worth noting that:

> You can end the spell early by using an action to dismiss it. (PHB, p. 245)

So this spell would only last as long as you wanted. If you are trying to force yourself to do something, that takes some out of the teeth out of the tactic.

Comment: Though the other answer is equally correct, I selected this one because the ability to end the spell early is a good reason to not even bother. Thanks! :)

Comment: I suppose you could cast this spell on yourself multiple times, with the terms of each Geas being, in part, that you take damage if you remove any of the other Geas spells from yourself. But this begs the question of whether or not a single action would remove all the spells at once, which deserves to be its own question.

Comment: Could you do that in a single Geas? "I am bound to do X, and must not remove this spell from myself." While you could still end the spell, it would get to bite you once. I can imagine this being used to enforce oaths, for example.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. In the absence of text defining specific timing of a trigger and event (like counterspell, which specifies that it takes effect before the targeted spell goes off), a result happens after its trigger finishes. So you'd finish your action ending the spell, and then the spell would try to hurt you but couldn't because it would already have been ended. (Support for this rule can be found on DMG, p. 252)

Comment: It's also difficult (RAW) to justify the idea that you could cast Geas on yourself more than once. Because once you cast the first one, you're charmed by yourself. And a charmed creature can't "target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects." (PHB, p. 290). Although there's some room for interpretation, it's hard to argue that a spell whose main effect is to damage you (conditionally) is anything other than a "harmful magical effect." (The reason you're casting it is helpful, but the spell itself is harmful).

Comment: Could part of the Geas be that target forgets that the Geas is applied (can't purposely cancel it if you don't remember it right....) this would help to get around the limitation of ending it early

Comment: The command must be understood in order to be able to carry it out. If the victim somehow forgets the command (in a manner that overrules its magical nature), it is unaffected by the Geas. Personally though, I houserule a Geas as a magically induced OCD, rather than extortion, as it prevents a host of loopholes that the caster would have to close with the right wording of the command. That way, it is also possible to prevent yourself from ending the spell, as you simply wouldn't want to while affected by the Geas.

Answer (score 3):

## You can target yourself

The only requirements are

> on a creature that you can see within range

You are a creature, you can see yourself - unless you are blinded, invisible or something like that - and you are within range. You are a valid target.

For reference, [Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/05/25/you-are-a-creature-can-you-see-yourself/) talks about this targetting for other spells.

> I don't know about you, but when I look down, I can see myself. Blinding me would definitely change that. #DnD #Optics

Now, how does it affect you? RAW, it does what it says

> If the creature can understand you, it must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or become charmed by you for the duration. While the creature is charmed by you, it takes 5d10 psychic damage each time it acts in a manner directly counter to your instructions, but no more than once each day.

You will, awkwardly, have to roll a saving throw against yourself and be charmed by yourself (which doesn't actually change many things). If the PC tries to drink, he takes 5d10 damage.