# Can the Glamour bard's Mantle of Inspiration feature target the bard themself?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, targeting, bard

The [College of Glamour bard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#CollegeofGlamour)'s [Mantle of Inspiration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#MantleofInspiration-649) feature reads as follows (XGtE, p. 14; emphasis mine):

> As a bonus action, you can expend one use of your Bardic Inspiration to grant yourself a wondrous appearance. When you do so, **choose a number of creatures you can see and that can see you within 60 feet of you**, up to a number equal to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one). Each of them gains 5 temporary hit points. When a creature gains these temporary hit points, it can immediately use its reaction to move up to its speed, without provoking opportunity attacks.

Since technically you can see yourself, you can see your target and your target can see you. As such, when using this ability, can you target yourself with it?

Comment: Related: "[Do you count as “a creature within X feet” of yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157308)"

Comment: Related: [Can you target yourself while blinded or invisible?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104721/can-you-target-yourself-while-blinded-or-invisible), [Can you cast Geas on yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128593/can-you-cast-geas-on-yourself), [Can an invisible creature see themselves and their own gear?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152720/can-an-invisible-creature-see-themselves-and-their-own-gear), [Can you cast Banishment on yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47436/can-you-cast-banishment-on-yourself)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Mantle of Inspiration can target you, as long as you can see yourself

As you quoted, the [College of Glamour bard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#CollegeofGlamour)'s [Mantle of Inspiration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#MantleofInspiration-649) feature reads as follows (XGtE, p. 14):

> When you do so, **choose a number of creatures you can see and that can see you within 60 feet of you**, up to a number equal to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one).

You've correctly surmised that you can use Mantle of Inspiration to target yourself, as long as you can see yourself. If you can see yourself, then nothing prevents this from working.

Keep in mind that there are a number of things that may make it so you can't see yourself: being [heavily obscured](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight) by something such as darkness (nonmagical or magical, if you can't see through it) or fog, something else that imposes the [blinded](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Blinded) condition, being [invisible](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Invisible), etc. In such cases, if you can't see yourself, then you can't use features or spells that target "a creature you can see".

Answer (score 1):

### It depends whether you count as a creature within 60 feet of yourself

The Mantle of Inspiration targets creatures you can see (you can see yourself, so check that off), that can also see you (you can see yourself, so check that off), that are within 60 feet of you. And it's that last part that *might* cause issues. All the requirements besides being within 60 feet of yourself are met and the answer to this is left unclear, something your GM will have to decide. This question is discussed quite a bit in the following Q/A:

- [Do you count as "a creature within X feet" of yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157308)

Comment: But can you see yourself? You can see your hands, and if you look down you can see your legs etc, but you can't see your face for example. You can't see the whole wonderous you, not without a mirror. So it's not self-evidently clear you aren't obscuring your own view of yourself too much for this ability to work on yourself.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir You are capable of simply seeing yourself. Fifth edition uses standard English and I would certainly say that I am capable of seeing myself. I can't see another person fully either unless they spin around and I get every possible angle, so I'm not sure your argument holds. Here's an unofficial ruling ([a tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/05/25/you-are-a-creature-can-you-see-yourself)) from Jeremy Crawford as well as [a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152720) on whether an invisible creature can see themself, greatly implying a creature ordinarily can do so